# Implementing multiple buttons using MVC in Java

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I'm making a program which uses MVC in java. My problem is that I don't know how to implement ActionListeners and handle events, such as when a button is clicked. I know that the code should be in the controller, but I don't know how to implement it. So far I've made a couple buttons, and I want to make them actually do something when they're clicked. What code should I add to my view and write in the controller class?

Here's my View class so far:

```
package decryptor;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.io.File;

public class View
{
    private JFrame frame;

    private JPanel mainPanel;

    private JLabel instructions;
    private JLabel frequenciesFileLoadedLabel;
    private JLabel cipherFileLoadedLabel;

    private JButton frequenciesFileLoadButton;
    private JButton cipherFileLoadButton;

    private JButton decipherByRankButton;
    private JButton decipherByNearestFrequencyButton;

    private boolean cipherLoaded;
    private boolean frequenciesLoaded;

    public enum Buttons
    {
        FREQUENCIES_LOAD, CIPHER_LOAD, DECIPHER_RANK, DECIPHER_NEAREST;
    }

    public View()
    {
        cipherLoaded = false;
        frequenciesLoaded = false;

        frame = new JFrame("Text Decrypter");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20, 10));
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,400));

        frequenciesFileLoadedLabel = new JLabel("No file with character frequencies loaded");
        cipherFileLoadedLabel = new JLabel("No file to decipher loaded");

        frequenciesFileLoadButton = new JButton("Load character frequencies file");
        cipherFileLoadButton = new JButton("Load file to decipher");
        decipherByRankButton = new JButton("Decipher file by rank of character frequencies");
        decipherByRankButton.setEnabled(false);
        decipherByNearestFrequencyButton = new JButton("Decipher file by the nearest character frequency");
        decipherByNearestFrequencyButton.setEnabled(false);

        mainPanel.add(frequenciesFileLoadButton);
        mainPanel.add(frequenciesFileLoadedLabel);
        mainPanel.add(cipherFileLoadButton);
        mainPanel.add(cipherFileLoadedLabel);
        mainPanel.add(decipherByRankButton);
        mainPanel.add(decipherByNearestFrequencyButton);

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //label fonts etc
    }

    private void enableButtons()
    {
        if (cipherLoaded == true && frequenciesLoaded == true)
        {
            decipherByRankButton.setEnabled(true);
            decipherByNearestFrequencyButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private File loadFile()
    {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File( System.getProperty("user.home")));

        int fileChooserResult = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);

        if (fileChooserResult == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            return fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Error loading file. Please try again.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            return null;
        }
    }

    public File loadFrequencies()
    {
        File loadedFile = loadFile();

        if (loadedFile == null)
        {
            frequenciesLoaded = false;
            enableButtons();
            frequenciesFileLoadedLabel.setText("No file with character frequencies loaded");
            return loadedFile;
        }
        else
        {
            frequenciesLoaded = true;
            enableButtons();
            frequenciesFileLoadedLabel.setText("Character frequencies file loaded");
            return loadedFile;
        }
    }

    public File loadCiphered()
    {
        File loadedFile = loadFile();

        if (loadedFile == null)
        {
            cipherLoaded = false;
            enableButtons();
            cipherFileLoadedLabel.setText("No file to decipher loaded");
            return loadedFile;
        }
        else
        {
            cipherLoaded = true;
            enableButtons();
            cipherFileLoadedLabel.setText("File to decipher loaded");
            return loadedFile;
        }
    }

    public void fileOutput()
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "File deciphered and output to file \"output.txt\".");
    }

    public JButton getButton(Buttons button)
    {
        switch (button) 
        {
            case FREQUENCIES_LOAD: return frequenciesFileLoadButton;
            case CIPHER_LOAD: return cipherFileLoadButton;
            case DECIPHER_RANK: return decipherByRankButton;
            case DECIPHER_NEAREST: return decipherByNearestFrequencyButton;
            default: return null;
        }
    }
}
```

There is a fair bit wrong with the code and I will fix it, however my priority currently is to get my buttons to work. I have tried making methods that will return the button if the controller calls the method, however I feel like that's not the right way to go about things.

Comment: *"I know that the code should be in the controller"* and here is the core issue with trying to wrap another MVC on top of an existing MVC (which Swing is). The fact is, the controller really has no responsibility to be messing with the UI, beyond what the contract of the view provides. This decouples the controller from the view and makes it possible to devise multiple implementations of the view to which a single controller could be used to control.

Comment: It also means that the implementation details (like registering `ActionListener`s to buttons) isn't the responsibility of the controller, but is the responsibility of the view.  The view will communication changes to the controller via a defined contract

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of **The Canonical Way**™ to do this, but one way is to use Swing's own property change support and PropertyChangeListeners as a mechanism to notify listeners of changes to both the view and the model. For example say we created your enum, with modifications:

```
// smvc for "simple model view controller"
public enum SmvcButtons {
    FREQUENCIES_LOAD("Load Frequencies"), 
    CIPHER_LOAD("Load Cipher"), 
    DECIPHER_RANK("Decipher Rank"), 
    DECIPHER_NEAREST("Decipher Nearest");
    private String text;

    private SmvcButtons(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

and used this in some sort of model:

```
public class SmvcModel {
    // constant for our single property name
    public static final String SMVC_BUTTONS = "smvc buttons";
    // a more complex model will have multiple "bound" properties

    // the support object will register listeners on the model
    // and will notify them of changes in model state
    private SwingPropertyChangeSupport pcSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private SmvcButtons smvcButtons;


    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public SmvcButtons getSmvcButtons() {
        return smvcButtons;
    }

    public void setSmvcButtons(SmvcButtons smvcButtons) {
        SmvcButtons oldValue = null;
        SmvcButtons newValue = smvcButtons;
        this.smvcButtons = smvcButtons;
        pcSupport.firePropertyChange(SMVC_BUTTONS, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String name, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(name, listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(String name, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(name, listener);
    }
}
```

Here we notify the property change support object of changes to the smvcButtons field by firing the property change method in the setter method:

```
    public void setSmvcButtons(SmvcButtons smvcButtons) {
        SmvcButtons oldValue = null;
        SmvcButtons newValue = smvcButtons;
        this.smvcButtons = smvcButtons;
        pcSupport.firePropertyChange(SMVC_BUTTONS, oldValue, newValue);
    }
```

Now listeners will be notified of changes

Within the Controller, we have a listener that listens for this:

```
private class ModelListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        String text = ((SmvcButtons) evt.getNewValue()).getText() + "\n";
        view.appendTextAreaText(text);
    }
}
```

Say we have a view (kept simple just for illustration purposes) that uses the enum to create buttons, and uses a similar mechanism for notifying listeners of changes in state:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SmvcView extends JPanel {
    public static final String SMVC_BUTTONS = "smvc buttons";
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(30, 50);

    public SmvcView() {
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 3, 0));
        for (final SmvcButtons smvcBtn : SmvcButtons.values()) {
            JButton button = new JButton(smvcBtn.getText());
            btnPanel.add(button);
            button.addActionListener(e -> {
                Object oldValue = null;
                Object newValue = smvcBtn;
                firePropertyChange(SMVC_BUTTONS, oldValue, newValue);
            });
        }

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
        add(scrollPane);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public void appendTextAreaText(String text) {
        textArea.append(text);
    }
}
```

Note that the view attaches anonymous listeners to its buttons, and the only thing they do is to notify the component's innate property change support that a button has been pressed -- that's it. The goal is to keep the view as dumb as possible:

```
button.addActionListener(e -> {
    Object oldValue = null;
    Object newValue = smvcBtn;
    firePropertyChange(SMVC_BUTTONS, oldValue, newValue);
});
```

Then the controller could use a similar listener to listen for changes to the view:

```
private class ViewListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        model.setSmvcButtons((SmvcButtons) evt.getNewValue());
    }
}
```

All this above listener does is to change the state of the model based on the button press (again this example is **very** simple)

The whole thing could look like:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

public class SimpleMvc {

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SmvcModel model = new SmvcModel();
        SmvcView view = new SmvcView();
        new Controller(model, view);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleMvc");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(view);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

enum SmvcButtons {
    FREQUENCIES_LOAD("Load Frequencies"), 
    CIPHER_LOAD("Load Cipher"), 
    DECIPHER_RANK("Decipher Rank"), 
    DECIPHER_NEAREST("Decipher Nearest");
    private String text;

    private SmvcButtons(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}

class Controller {

    private SmvcModel model;
    private SmvcView view;

    public Controller(SmvcModel model, SmvcView view) {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;

        model.addPropertyChangeListener(SmvcModel.SMVC_BUTTONS, new ModelListener());
        view.addPropertyChangeListener(SmvcView.SMVC_BUTTONS, new ViewListener());
    }

    private class ModelListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            String text = ((SmvcButtons) evt.getNewValue()).getText() + "\n";
            view.appendTextAreaText(text);
        }
    }

    private class ViewListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            model.setSmvcButtons((SmvcButtons) evt.getNewValue());
        }
    }

}

class SmvcModel {
    public static final String SMVC_BUTTONS = "smvc buttons";
    private SwingPropertyChangeSupport pcSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private SmvcButtons smvcButtons;


    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public SmvcButtons getSmvcButtons() {
        return smvcButtons;
    }

    public void setSmvcButtons(SmvcButtons smvcButtons) {
        SmvcButtons oldValue = null;
        SmvcButtons newValue = smvcButtons;
        this.smvcButtons = smvcButtons;
        pcSupport.firePropertyChange(SMVC_BUTTONS, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String name, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(name, listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(String name, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(name, listener);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class SmvcView extends JPanel {
    public static final String SMVC_BUTTONS = "smvc buttons";
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(30, 50);

    public SmvcView() {
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 3, 0));
        for (final SmvcButtons smvcBtn : SmvcButtons.values()) {
            JButton button = new JButton(smvcBtn.getText());
            btnPanel.add(button);
            button.addActionListener(e -> {
                Object oldValue = null;
                Object newValue = smvcBtn;
                firePropertyChange(SMVC_BUTTONS, oldValue, newValue);
            });
        }

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
        add(scrollPane);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public void appendTextAreaText(String text) {
        textArea.append(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice way to reuse existing functionality

Comment: Dear @HovercraftFullOfEels, isn't the JFrame code related to the View part? Shouldn't it be included somewhere into the SmvcView class? I'm a bit confused how this pattern should be correctly implemented in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about just adding an action listener, you just implement action listener and then add it to your buttons...

```
public class View implements ActionListener{

 cipherFileLoadButton.addActionListener(this);
 // etc listener to all buttons
 }

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object o = e.getSource();

   if(o == cipherFileLoadButton){
      /*
       * Do stuff
      */
     }
   }
```

Comment: I have 2 or more buttons, then do I create a separate class that implements ActionListener for each button?

Answer (score -2):

I can't remember it well but it looks like this:

```
btn.setOnclickListener(new OnclickListener(){
    ...// Override some methods to implement your business code.
}
);
```

or the lamda way:

```
btn.setOnclickListener(()->{
    ....// Override some methods to implement your business code.
});
```

I believe that your ide have some auto-fix function to help you complete those code. :)

Comment: here `btn` is the Button Object

Comment: There is no `setOnClickLIstener(...)` method in a Swing JButton.

Comment: I checked my previous code file and it should be like btn.addActionListener(...)

Comment: But also this question isn't about how to add listeners to JButtons, but how to wire the buttons into a valid MVC design structure, so even if you [edit]ed your answer and corrected the code, the answer would still be incorrect. You may wish to delete it.